# TclOO: class logger mixin

Tags: class, logging, tcl, mixins

Please recommend TclOO class logger mixin/trait.

Logger included with [tcllib 1.19](https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/log/logger.html) breaks when used as class logger:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
package require logger
package require logger::utils
::oo::class create Main {
    variable log
    constructor {} {
        set this_inst [namespace current]
        set this_klaz [info object class $this_inst]
        set log [::logger::init $this_klaz]
        ::logger::utils::applyAppender \
        -appender "console" \
        -appenderArgs {-conversionPattern {%d \[%p\] \[%M\] %m}} \
        -serviceCmd $log
    }
    method invoke {} {
        ${log}::info "hello"
    }
}
set main [Main new]
$main invoke
```

Producing object namespace:

```
2018/05/15 08:54:43 [info] [::oo::Obj12] hello
```

Instead of class/method namespace:

```
2018/05/15 08:54:43 [info] [::Main::invoke] hello
```

Comment: Yep. `namespace current` isn't going to produce the information that you were expecting here. It might take me a while to explain what the issue is, but the core issue is that the information you want isn't found in the way that the non-TclOO-aware logger wants to get it.

Comment: Perhaps there is an example of proper class namespace access and a specific place in `logger.tcl` source to fix that? https://github.com/tcltk/tcllib/blob/master/modules/log/logger.tcl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a **bug** in `::logger::utils::createLogProc` in [loggerUtils.tcl](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/artifact/44eb0c98fa16e656) in that the `%M` substitution is not aware of TclOO. If it was, it wouldn't be using the name of the object that the method was invoked on, but rather the name of the method. (It appears that it was designed to work with [incr Tcl], which *does* name methods like you appear to want.)

---

Ideally you'd be setting up the logger once per class, not once per instance. Here's how you'd do that:

```
package require logger
package require logger::utils
::oo::class create Main {
    variable log
    self {
        variable log
        method init {} {
            set log [::logger::init [self]]
            ::logger::utils::applyAppender \
                -appender "console" \
                -appenderArgs {-conversionPattern {%d \[%p\] \[%M\] %m}} \
                -serviceCmd $log
        }
        method logger {} {return $log}
    }
    constructor {} {
        set log [[self class] logger]
    }
    method invoke {} {
        ${log}::info "hello"
    }
}
Main init
set main [Main new]
$main invoke
```

But that doesn't fix the bug. That's actually because it looks up the value for `%M` substitution like this:

```
    if {[info level] < 2} {
        set method "global"
    } else {
        set method [lindex [info level -1] 0]
    }
```

whereas it probably ought to do something more like this:

```
    if {[info level] < 2} {
        set method "global"
    } elseif {[uplevel 1 {namespace which self}] == "::oo::Helpers::self"} {
        set method [uplevel 1 {string cat [self class] "::" [self method]}]
    } else {
        set method [lindex [info level -1] 0]
    }
```

Comment: works, thank you. filed a ticket: https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/tktview?name=e4d5ef01e7

Answer (score 0):

Pattern#1: provides command-to-method forwarder.

Mixin:

```
::oo::class create WithLogger {
    self {
        variable klaz_log
        method init_log {} {
             variable klaz_log [::logger::init [self]]
            ::logger::utils::applyAppender ... $klaz_log
        }
        method klaz_log {} {
            return $klaz_log
        }
    }
    method withLogger {} {
        set this_klaz [self class]
        $this_klaz init_log
        set klaz_log [$this_klaz klaz_log]
        {*}"proc log {level args} {tailcall ${klaz_log}::\${level} {*}\$args}"
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
::oo::class create Main {
    mixin -append WithLogger
    constructor {} {
        my withLogger ; # needs setup
    }
    method invoke {} {
        log info "hello" ; # uses command-to-method forwarder
    }
}

set main [Main new]
$main invoke
```

Output:

```
2018/05/16 15:08:59 [info] [::Main::invoke] hello
```